# What are server resources?

Tags: http2, multiplexing

I am reading about Priority concept of HTTP/2 but I'm not sure how it can be implement in a real server-client system. As I can see, Priority informs server what stream should be sent to client earlier and later.

However, I don't know what will happen if 2 stream A and B both have a dependency on C. This link http://undertow.io/blog/2015/04/27/An-in-depth-overview-of-HTTP2.html said:

"if stream A and B have a dependency on C, and A has a weighting of 1 and B has a weighting of 10 then B should receive 10 times amount of server resources as A".

I don't know what is "server resources", what will manage them (maybe server)  and how it can manage them.

Comment: I think it's basically bandwidth and scheduling priority.

Comment: @Ishi I think about bandwidth, too. But I wanna know how server handles it. Do you know that?

Answer (score 1):

Server resource is the resource in your web server.

From Wikipedia:

> A web server is a computer system that processes requests via HTTP,
>   the basic network protocol used to distribute information on the World
>   Wide Web. The term can refer to the entire system, or specifically to
>   the software that accepts and supervises the HTTP requests.

[image]

*HTTP/2* was designed to overcome many of the shortcomings of *HTTP/1.1*, particularly with how content is delivered over a network. Users see improvements in page load speed and responsiveness, while website administrators see lower resource usage. The result is a faster experience with no change to the existing functionality of the web.

You can see at here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I do need to know how server can use its resources for priority streams. Is one of them are bandwidth? if that's right, how does server use bandwidth to make sure higher priority stream will come earlier?

Comment: @minhkstn I read at here: https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-http2-all-about/ (almost information at here. I can't explain all in a question). You can see bandwidth also a part of them.